# Axios when changing instance headers other instances change too

Tags: javascript, axios

There are axios instances like this

```
// @flow
import axios, { type Axios } from 'axios';
import { HOST } from 'constants/host';

// Set config defaults when creating the instance
export const AppApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${HOST.APP_API.URL}${HOST.APP_API.API_PREFIX}`,
});

export const MenuApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${HOST.MENU_API.URL}${HOST.MENU_API.API_PREFIX}`,
});

export const setAuthToken = (authToken: string, api: Axios) => {
  api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = authToken;
};
```

And there you can notice the handy `setAuthToken` function.

It's used after I get auth token, and set it into the instance.

But whenever I change any instance headers all other instances change too.

Even the default axios object.
If I do

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'afds';
```

All instances change.

Is this some bug, or do I miss something here?

This how its done in the docs.

https://github.com/axios/axios

see "Custom instance defaults"

Comment: axios.defaults.header[index].common['Authorization'] = authToken. Have you tried setting it using index? Please check https://github.com/axios/axios#creating-an-instance

Comment: Would be better if you show your header code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with axios.

The work around is to add empty object hierarchy like this.

```
export const AppApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${HOST.APP_API.URL}${HOST.APP_API.API_PREFIX}`,
  headers: { common: {} },
});

export const MenuApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${HOST.MENU_API.URL}${HOST.MENU_API.API_PREFIX}`,
  headers: { common: {} },
});
```

More info here

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1664

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change the defaults of that instance, not axios.

```
export const MenuApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${HOST.MENU_API.URL}${HOST.MENU_API.API_PREFIX}`,
});
```

For example, you can set the token like

```
MenuApi.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'afds';
```

and not

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'afds';
```

Otherwise, it would change in all the instances.

Comment: whenever I change any instance headers all other instances change too.